# Can mongoose do such thing?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

DB collection is like:
        "suid" : "8986691b1db3d99b6fbe27cceac2e19c",
        "auid" : "22e7e5632acb4ac154b9bcb95710ca38",
        "msg" : "ceshi1",
        "ctime" : ISODate("2013-05-22T03:52:26.344Z"),
        "sended" : true,
        "__v" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("519c411351db351236000001")

MongoDB shell command is:
db.runCommand({"group":{ns:"messages",key:{"auid":true},"initial":{"lastmsgtime":0},condition:{auid:'456'},$reduce:function(doc,prev){senttime=doc.ctime.valueOf();if(senttime>prev.lastmsgtime){prev.suid=doc.suid;prev.lastmsgtime=new Date(senttime);}}, } })

Can mongoose do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't have direct support for `group`, so you need to access the native driver's [`group`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#group) method via your Mongoose model like this:

```js
Model.collection.group({"auid":true}, ...);
```